# Kommasetzung bei Nebensätzen bzw. ab wann gilt ein Satz eigentlich als Nebensatz?

Tags: subordinate-clause, comma, punctuation

Ich habe eine Frage zur Kommasetzung bei Nebensätzen. Folgende Sätze:

1. "Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer geeigneten Stelle und hoffe sehr, dass sich meine große Hoffnung erfüllt, in diesem Bereich, einen Neuanfang zu finden."

Ich bin mir unsicher, über die Kommasetzung des Nebensatzes "in diesem Bereich". Ist das überhaupt ein Nebensatz (ich könnte es so interpretieren), oder ist das Teil des Hauptsatzes?

2. Mit der von Ihnen ausgeschriebenen Stelle, beginnend zum zweiten Quartal, hoffe ich noch einmal sehr, eine Chance zu erhalten, meinem Wunsch nachzugehen, im Bereich A, B oder C meine Fähigkeiten weiterbilden zu können.

Hier sind vermutlich zuviele Kommas, aber ich habe mal Alle eingefügt, die ich vertreten könnte.  Speziell "eine Chance zu erhalten" könnte man als Nebensatz weglassen; deshalb der Kommataeinschub. "meinem Wunsch nachzugehen", kann man als Aufzählung und auch als weiteren Nebensatz interpretieren.

Danke für die Hilfe.

Comment: Das Komma nach "Bereich" im ersten Beispiel ist falsch. "In diesem Bereich" ist eine adverbiale Bestimmung des Ortes, die den Satz "einen Neuanfang finden" näher bestimmt ("Wo einen Neuanfang finden?").  —— Die Definition eines Satzes ist recht kompliziert. Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_(Grammatik)

Comment: Danke dir. Hast auch nen Einwand zu 2.?

Answer (score 1):

Das letzte Komma in Satz 1 ist falsch - Wie im Kommentar schon angedeutet, handelt es sich be "in diesem Bereich" um eine adverbiale Bestimmung, die nicht mit Kommas abgetrennt wird.

Der zweite Satz ist stilistisch ziemlich ungeschickt: Drei Infinitive als Schachtelung sind wirklich ein bißchen viel - Hier würde man die Infinitive wahrscheinlich wesentlich besser durch eine Substantivierung oder eine Auslagerung in einen Nebensatz - oder noch besser - Aufteilung in mehrere Hauptsätze ersetzen. ("sehe ich eine Chance für meine Wunschstelle im Bereich A, B, C" o.Ä.). Auch der Einschub "beginnend im zweiten Quartal" sollte eigentlich anders ausgedrückt werden - Der Satz wirkt "gestopft voll" mit allen möglichen Aussagen. Ich würde den unbedingt aufteilen und grundsätzlich anders formulieren.

Zu den Kommas: sind §75 der Rechtschreibregeln macht für Infinitivgruppen folgende Regel auf:

> Infinitivgruppen grenzt man mit Komma ab, wenn eine der folgenden Bedingungen erfüllt ist.

und zählt folgende Bedingungen auf:

1. Einleitung mit einer Präposition ("um, ohne, statt, anstatt, außer, als") - Hier nicht der Fall
2. Abhängigkeit von einem Substantiv (in diesem Fall "die Chance", "der Wunsch"). Eine Ausnahme macht hier das Komma optional, "solange keine Missverständnisse entstehen", und auch in den nicht genannten Fällen *dürfen* Kommas gesetzt werden, um Missverständnisse zu vermeiden.
3. Abhängigkeit von einem Korrelat ("Es") oder einem Verweiswort (hier nicht der Fall).

In allen anderen Fällen sind Kommas bei Infinitivgruppen optional (d.h.: keins deiner Kommas ist wirklich falsch).

Alle Kommas bei Infinitiven in deinem Satz fallen in die Kategorie (2) oder ("nicht erfasst"), sind also grundsätzlich optional. Allerdings wird der Satz, wenn du die Kommas weglässt, ziemlich unverständlich (allerdings auch mit Kommas stilistisch nicht wesentlich besser).

Ein Vorschlag:

> Ich hoffe sehr auf die Chance, mit dieser Stelle ab dem zweiten Quartal meinen Wunsch erfüllen zu können, mich in den Bereichen A, B, und C weiterzubilden.

(Grundsätzliche Anmerkung: Dein zukünftiger Arbeitgeber will dich nicht in erster Linie einstellen, weil er dich unbedingt *weiterbilden* möchte - Er möchte, dass du für ihn arbeitest! Das ist also nicht unbedingt ein starkes Argument, dich einzustellen: Eventuell ersetzt du "weiterzubilden" durch "mich engagieren")

Comment: Vielen Dank für deine Hilfe. Ich habe den Satz jetzt komplett umgeschrieben:"Ich bin auf der Suche nach einer geeigneten Stelle und hoffe sehr, dass sich mein großer Wunsch erfüllt mich, auf dem Gebiet der XYZ, im Bereich der A, B oder C, behaupten zu können. Die von Ihnen ausgeschriebene Stelle, zum zweiten Quartal, würde mir die Chance auf diesen Neuanfang geben." Kommasetzung ok, oder würde vor "zum zweiten Quartal" jetzt doch wieder kein Komma stehen? Ich würde vermuten, dass dies wieder unter Punkt 2. fällt, also optional ist.